# Constrain column view to one line

Tags: 2007

I have a task list that has a single-line text column, a Status column and a Modified By column (among others).

It appears that the default view has the single-line text column taking up all the room it can, making the status and modified by column go to 2-line formatting.  I'd like to force the Status and Modified By columns to display on only one line, and let the single-line text go to 2-lines if it needs to.

How would I go about getting the single-line text column to lose priority for space?

**EDIT:**  I did the cheap fix of making the column names larger, but would like a better solution (I used underscores).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SharePoint does not allow this out-of-the-box.

You can:

- customize column width [using SharePoint Designer](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepointcustomization/thread/0477a19a-aca7-4a4f-b1ab-1e4062fe1d70) (but it may break some things),
- dig into this [jQuery solution](http://kjellsj.blogspot.com/2009/06/sharepoint-jquery-setting-td-column.html) (previous SharePoint+jQuery experience would be useful; let me just warn you that you may run into the loading the [jQuery-from-Google-CDN-fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/879137/problem-with-jquery-in-internet-explorer-8) problem).